# Regex Conversion issues from PHP to Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Basically, I don't have knowledge on how to build a regex, currently I am having 
PHP regex as

```
/^[\w\s'-\/\.\,\(\)\\\]{0,100}$/
```

But now I want to convert this regex into Javascript compatible regex.

How to make the above regex compatible in Javascript?

Comment: Use http://regex101.com to translate from one to the other.

Comment: FYI, you don't need to escape special characters within a character class so you can lose a lot of those backslashes

Answer (score 1):

You have too many escape characters in your regex, other thatn that, it should Work.

So here's a modified version that should Work, although it's a strange regex that will always match zero to 100 characters:

```
/^[\w\s'-\/\.,\(\)\\]{0,100}$/
```

Answer (score 1):

The backslash character is used to escape metacharacters. In sets (between square brackets) you don't need to escape most metacharacters.

This will do as well:

`^[\w\s'-/.,()\\]{0,100}$`

In PHP, you can escape a backslash with three or four backslashes:

`\\\` - Escapes a backslash (PHP)

`\\\\` - Also escapes a backslash (PHP)

But please don't mix and match as it's confusing and prone to mishaps.

With JavaScript, you have to represent a literal backslash with exactly two backslashes.

`\\` - Escapes a backslash (JS)

Here is a further resource: https://javascript.info/regexp-character-sets-and-ranges#no-escaping-in-

If you have a couple hours to spend, I learnt most of what I know about regexes with Sam's Teach Yourself. The material is focused on PCRE, but is 98% useful for JS as well. You'll be happier; regexes are tough.